# Error codes when launching Flutter App on physical ios device

Tags: xcode, flutter

I tried to launch a flutter app into my ios device but keep getting these errors.

I've tried everything online. I have no clue what to do.

Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

```
Code Signing Error: Failed to create provisioning profile. The app ID "io.flutter.plugins.firebaseMlVisionExample" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseMlVisionExample' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseMlVisionExample'.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.2'
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.2'
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.2'
```

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

The flutter app should be installed on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

At this point you should open the iOS project in XCode and follow Apple's instructions for preparing your application for distribution. This will resolve the errors you are seeing.  See: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: I'm not trying to distribute my app on the app store. I'm just trying to run a prototype version on my iphone 7.

Comment: Exactly. In order to run your app on a device, you need a developer's signing certificate, which means you need to enroll as an Apple developer.  After that open the project in XCode and check the box to allow XCode to "automatically manage signing."

Answer (score 0):

Open `your_project_folder/ios/Runner.xcworkspace`, the Xcode will be launched. Then choose the `Team` under `Signing` section (a Personal Team option should in the options). If some error appeared, try to modify the `Bundle Identifier` under `Indentity` section to some unique string. Now you can debug your flutter app on the ios device.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, the reason is because I did not select my development team for project Runner. On apple developer console, I have my bundle ID there, but I did not specify which team I will use for this project. To solve it, use xcode to open the runner of your app, go to signing/capabilities select your team.